# Python's slice notation when a two-word start with same string and it should return True

Tags: python, string

I need to check whether a two-word string start with same string (letter) should return True. I am not sure which slicing method apply here. I gone through the various post here but could not find the required one. Based on my code, the result always give 'none'.

```
def word_checker(name):
    if name[0] =='a'  and name[::1] == 'a':
        return True

print(word_checker('abc adgh'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string on spaces and check the first letter of each split:

```
def word_checker(name):
    first, second = name.split()
    return first[0] == 'a' and second[0] == 'a'

print(word_checker('abc adgh'))
```

**Output**

```
True
```

But the previous code will only return `True` if both words start with `'a'`, if both must start with the same letter, you can do it like this:

```
def word_checker(name):
    first, second = name.split()
    return first[0] == second[0]

print(word_checker('abc adgh'))
print(word_checker('bar barfoo'))
print(word_checker('bar foo'))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `'bar barfoo'` should also return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

`'abc adgh'[::1]` will simply return the entire string. See [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) for more details (list slicing is similar to string slicing).

Instead, you need to split by whitespace, e.g. using `str.split`. A functional method can use `map` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def word_checker(name):
    a, b = map(itemgetter(0), name.split())
    return a == b

print(word_checker('abc adgh'))  # True
print(word_checker('abc bdgh'))  # False
```